# Is the Empty Set a Manifold

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, definition

Is the empty set $\emptyset$ a $C^1$-Manifold?

If this is personal preference, as is $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ for example, then what are the reasons for/against this choice?

Comment: What is your definition of a $C^1$-manifold?

Comment: In short: A $C^1$-Manifold of dimension k is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is locally given by the graph of a continously differentiable map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^k \supset G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$

Comment: If that is your definition, then yes, the emptyset is a manifold, as you can easily check: at every one of its points that local condition is satisfied.

Comment: Since you ask for my definition, are there then definitions where the empty set would not be a manifold?

Comment: If you follow the formal definition then of course it is, since you will use an atlas of empty charts.

Comment: My point was that it is impossible to answer the question you asked without reference to a concrete definition.ç

Comment: @studiosus, rather, an empty atlas of charts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you decided that $\emptyset$ is not a manifold, you'd have to write things like

> the boundary of a manifold with boundary is a manifold unless it is empty

or

> The preimage of a regular value under a smooth map is a smooth submanifold, unless it is empty

or you'd have to come up with a funny way of stating the usual proof that a volume form $\nu$ over a closed manifold $M$ is not exact, which usually uses Stoke's theorem asserting that $\int_Md\eta=\int_{\partial M}\eta$, where in that case $\partial M$ is empty.

In all, you'd litter everything with lots of «unless it is empty»...

Comment: If you do decide that it is a manifold, on the other hand, you have to pick a dimension for it, decide if its connected, decide what is its tangent bundle, its algebra of differential forms, and so on. The emptyset is a lot of work either way. If you want the statement «the dimension of a product of manifolds is the sum of the dimension of the factors», with no qualifications, for example, you don't have a lot of options for the dimension of $\emptyset$ and they are not the most amicable —at least at first sight.ç

Comment: If you let the dimension vary over the manifold then many of these problems disappear.  You only have to define the dimension at each point of the manifold, and $\emptyset\times X$ has no points. Also it's disconnected, it's ring of scalars is the trivial ring, the tensor bundle is the only module over this ring, and the exterior algebra is the only algebra over this ring. I think that you should be able to avoid ever treating it as a special case.

Comment: So I gather it's a choice between sacrificing a rigorous definition of manifold or it being an unexciting special case in proofs?

Comment: where did you get the idea that one of the choices is "sacrificing a rigorous definition"?!

Comment: @OscarCunningham, but there are basic facts of nature that require a dimension for the whole thing. For example, Poincaré duality would be quite obnoxious to state on a manifold with components of different dimension, and we all agree that Poincaré duality is one of the most fundamental properties of manifolds.

Answer (score 4):

Some people demand in their definitions that manifolds be connected. Some people consider the empty set to not be connected (for the same reason $1$ isn't prime). The intersection of these sets of people must therefore consider the empty set not to be a manifold.

If you do allow disconnected manifolds then note that there are two separate ways of dealing with the notion of dimension. Some people say that a manifold must locally look like $\mathbb R^k$ for some $k$, where $k$ can vary over the manifold (it has to be fixed on each connected component, but different components can have different dimensions). Other people say that you have to specify a particular $k$ first, and then every point in the manifold has to locally look like $\mathbb R^k$ for that particular $k$. In the former case $\emptyset$ is a manifold, in the later case there are many manifolds with underlying set $\emptyset$: one for each dimension.